# ES6 import (or is d3 just different somehow?)

Tags: d3.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs, rollupjs

**TL;DR**:

1. Using Rollup, can I import D3 like Debug or can I only build a custom library?

**Background**

I'm trying to build my first webapp with [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org), [D3](https://d3js.org) (v4 - ES2015) and others. In search of an education, I followed [Jason Lengstorf's tutorial](https://code.lengstorf.com/learn-rollup-js/). There I learned how to import [Debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) (CommonJS) and use its facilities. Works like a champ. I then tried to use D3 in the same way, only there are no default exports so used `import * as d3 from 'd3'` instead of the `import debug from debug`-style. For love or money I can't get it to work. I keep getting errors that look like:

> 'request' is not exported by
>   node_modules/d3-request/build/d3-request.js
>   https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1376) with the Rollup guys. They are busy and gave me what they could — and I remain stumped. Both of Mike Bostock's examples ([I](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/bb09af4c39c79cffcde4) and [II](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/97557a39b4bfc8229786c8bccb54074d)) just show how to build custom bundles, not how to import into working code a la Debug (which is, again, CommonJS not ES2015 like D3). Is that the only way to use it? I have not experimented with another ES2015 library (not that I know any) so I don't know if this is D3-specific or I just don't understand how to deal with ES2015 libraries generally (or just simply don't understand browser-based architecture period).

**Follow-on questions**

2. Is there a web app architecture tutorial/book/something that includes ES2015-specific issues?
3. There seems to be as many project structures out there as people coding. Is there One True Church? Do I just have to keep bleeding from my eyes until I get my own, phoenix-like kung fu about all this (reference [Jose Aguinaga's piece](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f))?